# Why do viewPDF failed to start?

Tags: ubuntu

I have just started to work with Latex in Ubuntu environment using Kile. I can produce a pdf file in the working directory hwoever I get an error message when I built the program:

```
[ViewPDF] failed to start
```

Here is a minimal code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

Hello! This is the first doc written with Latex in Ubuntu!

\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is the problem solved now?

Comment: No! It was just forgotten when I cut / past the code!

Comment: Are you missing a PDF viewer (Okular, specifically)? See [this page for the fix to an identical error](http://ubuntudigest.blogspot.com/2011/10/problem-in-kile-viewpdf-failed-to-start.html).

Comment: In Kile open `Settings -> Configure Kile`, choose `Tools -> Build` and click on `ViewPDF`. Now you should see wich viewer is called (e.g. `acroread`, `Okular`, `evince`). Be sure that you have the specified viewer installed.

Comment: Yes! Thank you for your help. I have just installed Okular and all is going very well! Please could you answer the question? Thank you!

Comment: @Strömungsmechanik Do I understand you right, that your problem is not sovled yet? If so, could you comment on how you compile your file to get the pdf?

Comment: @crixstox Thank you! I use the button  above: PDFLaTeX to compile and the button ViewPDF. The pdf file is successfully generated and I can view it. However, I get a huge number of disturbing messages, such as finished with exit code 1, Not defining \perthousand or \macro and many of Overfull \vbox too high were detected!!! That was errors, warnings and a lot of badboxes. I believe that the pdf is well generated but I think that is a pity to get such error messages every time I use Kile. The problem will be asked when I make real errors!! Do you have any idea about what one could do?

Comment: @Strömungsmechanik Now I am buffled! Do this error occur, when you compile youe MWE above?

Comment: @crixstox no!But they occur when I compile the original document. Thank you!!

Comment: @Strömungsmechanik In this case please consider asking a new question, with a corresponding new MWE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it was pointed out in a comment, the problem is probably that the viewer that is called by Kile is not installed.

To determine which viewer is used and to probably chage it you can proceed as follows:
In Kile open `Settings -> Configure Kile`, choose `Tools -> Build` and click on `ViewPDF`. Now you should see wich viewer is called (e.g. `acroread`, `Okular`, `evince`) and you can change it according to your preferences.

At last ensure that you have the specified viewer installed.

Comment: thank you for your answer. However, nothing has been changed! I set Okular in View PDF and all the 6 results of Ubuntu software center with regard to Okular are already installed!!